# How can I setup a Wilcard DNS Entry on pfSense?

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, dnsmasq

How can I set up Wildcard DNS on a pfSense embedded device running pfSense 2.0?

Details:

- pfSense uses dnsmasq as a DNS forwarder
- Running the current pfSense release, 2.0
- Running on a [Netgate
  M1n1wall](http://store.netgate.com/Netgate-m1n1wall-2D3-2D13-Black-P216.aspx) embedded firewall.
- I have root access via ssh if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was no quick google search or RTFM. After visiting many sites, many dead ends, and a little trial and error, I figured this out:

1. Log in to pfSense 2.0 instance via the web interface.
2. Go to Services-> DNS Forwarder (http://pfSensense_url/services_dnsmasq.php)
3. Click the Advanced button Add as many of the following as you need, each entry on a new line.

   address=/dev/127.0.0.1

Where dev is the end of the wildcard entry, and 127.0.0.1 is the ip that these wildcard names will resolve to. Think of dev as *.dev, but only list the part after the dot. So myhost.dev, myhost.subdomain.dev, and anything else that ends in .dev and is not defined elsewhere, will resolve to the ip provided.